# Windows Server 2012 R2: Check online for updates from Microsoft Update via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

Is there a way using PowerShell to "Check online for updates from Microsoft Update" on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Comment: Questions about how to manage Windows are off-topic at StackOverflow, as they are not about programming. Try SuperUser or ServerFault instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using the PowerShell Module [PSWindowsUpdate](https://i1.gallery.technet.s-msft.com/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc#content) and the following commands act as the same like clicking on "Check online for updates from Microsoft Update" in "Control Panel" -> "System and Security" -> "Windows Update"

```
Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
Get-WUList -WindowsUpdate
```

PS: The PowerShell Module [PSWindowsUpdate](https://i1.gallery.technet.s-msft.com/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc#content) is installed by unzipping the downloaded zip file into the directory "%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules".

Comment: Linking to off-site resources is discouraged. If Technet Gallery ever goes offline ([and it will](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamblog/technet-gallery-retirement), it's in retirement phase), the answer isn't of much use.

Comment: @vonPryz Technet is an official Microsoft site, but it looks like the actually will retire that site. "We are retiring the TechNet Gallery. Make sure to back up your code."

Comment: The code has been moved to: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWindowsUpdate/2.2.0.2 and you can use "Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate" so you dont need to go to the site to install it.